# Multiple auto margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm making a mini fantasy football manager website with some of my mates, I'm trying to have my player icons aligned in the same manner they do on [ones like this](http://fantasy.premierleague.com/). At the moment I'm not under any restrictions as to the best method of the HTML coding, so whether it be with divs, tables etc isn't restricted.

[this is what I have at the moment](http://jsfiddle.net/UYDKa/) but I'm, looking to have all the divs spaced out evenly, so the GK is in the middle, the 3 Strikers are more spaced out than the 4 Midfielders etc. Normally I'm good at this kind of CSS stuff but its just left my brain today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline-block on the children, text-align: center on the wrapper AND set the font-size to 0 on the wrapper so the whitespace in the markup won't affect the centering of the elements,

http://jsfiddle.net/UYDKa/1/